# Background image web view

Tags: iphone

I have a UIWebView witch load a file ( file.htm), i would like to put a background image (image.png) to my web view. How i can Do this Please ?

thanks four your answers.

Comment: Why don't you set the bg with css to your body tag?

Comment: If you want to change the contents background use CSS. Otherwise I think you can place an UIImageView with your image behind the webview

Answer (score 0):

I want to open stackoverflow in my browser but also want a background image to be there...what do you think the difference it will make?

Put a imageview in background of webview..but still it doesn't make any sense to me..

Answer (score 0):

Put a uiimageview with image.png .upon this add your webview and then add this line of code:

```
webview.backgrouncolor = [uicolor clearcolor];
```